# Parse words in a column separated by non-alphabetic characters

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a column of words separated by either a '/' or '-'.

```
|Column1|
|box-apple/bike-box|
|apple/orange-box-box-box|
```

I want to parse the repeat words keeping the only the first instance and the '/' or '-' as they are significant.

```
Output
|Column1|
|box-apple/bike|
|apple/orange-box|
```

reproducible data set:

```
data.frame(x = c(('box-apple/bike-box'),('apple/orange-box-box-box')))
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Is this even possible to do?

Okay I now got it to work using:

```
sapply(table10$CONCEPT_NAME, function(x) paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " - "))), collapse = " - "))
```

but I can only get back that one column from the data frame. Is there anyway I can apply this function and get all the columns from my data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay figured it out. this is the code that makes the above issue work:

```
sapply(table10$CONCEPT_NAME, function(x) paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " - "))), collapse = " - "))
```

and to return the original data from

```
table10$CONCEPT_NAME <- sapply(table10$CONCEPT_NAME, function(x) paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " - "))), collapse = " - "))
```

you just overwrite the column.